# How to show number of means +/- SE?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, lsmeans

I wanted to show the means and standard error with numbers, in the form of Mean +/- SE on top of each bar. Please help! Thank you.
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is the code I used but didn't give what I needed.

```html
data$rotation[data$Rot.trt %in% c("C2", "S2")]<-"TwoYear"
data$rotation[data$Rot.trt %in% c("C3", "S3", "O3")]<-"ThreeYear"
data$rotation[data$Rot.trt %in% c("C4", "S4", "O4", "A4")]<-"FourYear"
                                                             
  ggplot(data = data, aes(Crop, kg.ha, fill=Crop))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=kg.ha-se, ymax=kg.ha+se))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~rotation)+
  scale_fill_hue(c=45)
```

And here is the data

```js
     Date Plot  Rep Side    Crop  Rot Rot.Herb Rot.trt Herb.trt
1   8-Sep-14   11 1rep    W    corn 3rot   C3conv      C3     conv
2   8-Sep-14   11 1rep    E    corn 3rot    C3low      C3      low
3   8-Sep-14   13 1rep    W    corn 2rot    C2low      C2      low
4   8-Sep-14   13 1rep    E    corn 2rot   C2conv      C2     conv
5   8-Sep-14   18 1rep    W    corn 4rot    C4low      C4      low
6   8-Sep-14   18 1rep    E    corn 4rot   C4conv      C4     conv
7  10-Sep-14   23 2rep    W    corn 3rot   C3conv      C3     conv
8  10-Sep-14   23 2rep    E    corn 3rot    C3low      C3      low
9  10-Sep-14   24 2rep    W    corn 2rot    C2low      C2      low
10 10-Sep-14   24 2rep    E    corn 2rot   C2conv      C2     conv
11 10-Sep-14   28 2rep    W    corn 4rot   C4conv      C4     conv
12 10-Sep-14   28 2rep    E    corn 4rot    C4low      C4      low
13 10-Sep-14   34 3rep    W    corn 2rot    C2low      C2      low
14 10-Sep-14   34 3rep    E    corn 2rot   C2conv      C2     conv
15 10-Sep-14   37 3rep    W    corn 4rot    C4low      C4      low
16 10-Sep-14   37 3rep    E    corn 4rot   C4conv      C4     conv
17 10-Sep-14   38 3rep    W    corn 3rot   C3conv      C3     conv
18 10-Sep-14   38 3rep    E    corn 3rot    C3low      C3      low
19 12-Sep-14   44 4rep    W    corn 2rot   C2conv      C2     conv
20 12-Sep-14   44 4rep    E    corn 2rot    C2low      C2      low
21 12-Sep-14   46 4rep    W    corn 4rot    C4low      C4      low
22 12-Sep-14   46 4rep    E    corn 4rot   C4conv      C4     conv
23 12-Sep-14   48 4rep    W    corn 3rot    C3low      C3      low
24 13-Sep-14   48 4rep    E    corn 3rot   C3conv      C3     conv
25 15-Sep-14   14 1rep    W soybean 4rot    S4low      S4      low
26 15-Sep-14   14 1rep    E soybean 4rot   S4conv      S4     conv
27 15-Sep-14   16 1rep    W soybean 3rot   S3conv      S3     conv
28 15-Sep-14   16 1rep    E soybean 3rot    S3low      S3      low
29 15-Sep-14   19 1rep    W soybean 2rot    S2low      S2      low
30 15-Sep-14   19 1rep    E soybean 2rot   S2conv      S2     conv
31 15-Sep-14   25 2rep    W soybean 3rot    S3low      S3      low
32 15-Sep-14   25 2rep    E soybean 3rot   S3conv      S3     conv
33 15-Sep-14   27 2rep    W soybean 2rot   S2conv      S2     conv
34 15-Sep-14   27 2rep    E soybean 2rot    S2low      S2      low
35 15-Sep-14   29 2rep    W soybean 4rot   S4conv      S4     conv
36 15-Sep-14   29 2rep    E soybean 4rot    S4low      S4      low
   DIGSANo DIGSAWt SETFANo SETFAWt SETLUNo SETLUWt PANCANo PANCAWt
1       NA      NA       1    0.10      NA      NA      NA      NA
2       NA      NA       3   61.00      NA      NA      NA      NA
3       NA      NA       1    1.50      NA      NA      NA      NA
4       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
5        2    1.30       2   14.00       1    0.10      NA      NA
6       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
7       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
8       NA      NA       2    4.10      NA      NA      NA      NA
9       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
11       2    0.25      NA      NA       7    7.00      NA      NA
12      NA      NA      15   31.40       1    0.06      NA      NA
13      NA      NA       2    1.45      NA      NA      NA      NA
14      NA      NA       1    0.15      NA      NA      NA      NA
15      NA      NA       1    0.07      NA      NA      NA      NA
16      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
17      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
18       1    0.90       2    9.10      NA      NA      NA      NA
19      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
20      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
21       4    3.97       6   71.50       3    3.09      NA      NA
22      NA      NA       1    2.31       2    0.26      NA      NA
23      NA      NA       6    8.90     382  160.30      NA      NA
24      NA      NA      NA      NA     226  101.60      NA      NA
25       1    0.14       5   10.60      NA      NA      NA      NA
26      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
27      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
28      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
29       1    2.99      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
30      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
31      NA      NA       2   40.50      NA      NA      NA      NA
32      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
33      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
34      NA      NA       2    3.02      NA      NA       2    4.39
35      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
36      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
   ECHCGNo ECHCGWt ERBVINo ERBVIWt CYPESNo CYPESWt AMATANo AMATAWt
1       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       2   25.50
3       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       8    8.30
4       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       4    0.10
5        6   21.70      NA      NA      NA      NA       2    1.20
6       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00
7       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00
8       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
9       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.03
10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    1.57
11      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       2    0.01
12      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      11    5.30
13      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    0.03
14      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.03
15      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
16      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
17      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00
18      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
19      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.06
20      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      11   34.50
21      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
22      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
23      NA      NA       6    42.5      NA      NA      32   26.10
24      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       2    0.00
25      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       9   82.00
26      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       2    1.55
27      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    2.92
28      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      23   66.10
29      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       4   15.07
30      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    1.79
31      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      53  235.10
32      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       2    0.08
33      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       5    0.38
34       1   14.72       2    32.4      NA      NA      20   99.10
35      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
36      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      10  112.30
   CHEALNo CHEALWt SOLPTNo SOLPTWt PHYSUNo PHYSUWt POLCCNo POLCCWt
1        6    0.10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2       44  208.10      NA      NA       5    2.10      NA      NA
3       NA      NA      NA      NA       2   13.90      NA      NA
4       NA      NA      NA      NA       6    0.00      NA      NA
5       NA      NA      NA      NA       2    0.10      NA      NA
6       NA      NA      11    0.40       1    0.00      NA      NA
7       NA      NA       1    0.08      NA      NA      NA      NA
8       15   41.80       3    0.30      NA      NA      NA      NA
9        2    0.20      18    5.81      NA      NA      NA      NA
10      NA      NA       4    0.17      NA      NA      NA      NA
11      NA      NA       5    0.95      NA      NA      NA      NA
12      NA      NA       7    1.04      NA      NA      NA      NA
13      NA      NA       2    0.20       2    3.06      NA      NA
14      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
15       2    4.55       4    0.85       2    0.06      NA      NA
16      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
17       1    0.00       2    0.30      NA      NA      NA      NA
18       8   26.30       1    0.05      NA      NA      NA      NA
19      NA      NA      NA      NA      11    0.24      NA      NA
20       1   49.40      NA      NA       2    0.33      NA      NA
21      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    0.32      NA      NA
22      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    2.06      NA      NA
23       1      NA      NA      NA       6    0.35      NA      NA
24      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.04      NA      NA
25       5    8.00      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
26       1    0.08      NA      NA       1    0.03      NA      NA
27       4    0.34       1    0.10      NA      NA      NA      NA
28      86  262.10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
29       3    8.06      NA      NA       2    1.08      NA      NA
30      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
31      41  133.10       2    1.47      NA      NA      NA      NA
32      15    1.01       1    0.06      NA      NA      NA      NA
33       1    0.03       1    0.00       1    0.00      NA      NA
34       3    4.57       2    0.37      NA      NA      NA      NA
35      NA      NA       1    0.09      NA      NA      NA      NA
36      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
   POLPYNo POLPYWt ABUTHNo ABUTHWt TAROFNo TAROFWt EPHHTNo EPHHTWt
1       NA      NA       4    0.20       6    0.10      NA      NA
2       NA      NA      NA      NA       4    0.00      NA      NA
3       NA      NA       2    0.10      NA      NA      NA      NA
4       NA      NA      NA      NA      21    0.00       1    0.00
5       NA      NA       6    3.10       6    0.10       2    0.10
6       NA      NA      NA      NA       3    0.00      NA      NA
7       NA      NA       1    0.07       6    0.07      NA      NA
8       NA      NA      NA      NA       7    0.23      NA      NA
9       NA      NA      NA      NA      17    0.18       5    0.13
10      NA      NA      NA      NA      33    0.51      NA      NA
11      NA      NA       4    0.66       5    0.06       2    0.04
12      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    0.10       1    0.08
13      NA      NA      NA      NA       7    0.20      NA      NA
14      NA      NA      NA      NA      17    0.24      NA      NA
15       1    0.41       4    9.50      14    0.57      36    0.66
16      NA      NA      NA      NA      11    0.18      13    0.31
17      NA      NA       3    0.09       9    0.13      NA      NA
18      NA      NA       1    0.05      31    2.60      NA      NA
19      NA      NA      NA      NA       8    0.03      NA      NA
20       2    0.72      NA      NA       6    0.09      NA      NA
21      NA      NA      18   40.40       2    0.02       2    0.03
22      NA      NA      NA      NA       3    0.02      NA      NA
23      NA      NA       4    1.47       9    0.13      NA      NA
24      NA      NA      NA      NA       5    0.00      NA      NA
25      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
26      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
27      NA      NA       2    0.69       1    0.00      NA      NA
28      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
29      NA      NA       1    2.72       1    0.24      NA      NA
30      NA      NA      NA      NA      40    1.65      NA      NA
31      NA      NA       1    0.04      NA      NA      NA      NA
32      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
33       3    0.21      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
34      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.05      NA      NA
35      NA      NA       2    1.63       1    0.00      NA      NA
36      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
   CIRARNo CIRARWt SONARNo SONARWt MORALNo MORALWt OXASTNo OXASTWt
1       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2       NA      NA      NA      NA       5    0.00      NA      NA
3       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
4       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
5       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
6       NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
7       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
8       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
9       NA      NA       1    0.10      NA      NA      NA      NA
10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
11      NA      NA       1    0.02      NA      NA      NA      NA
12      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.14
13      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
14      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
15      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
16      NA      NA       1    0.01       1    0.02       1    0.00
17      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
18      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
19      NA      NA      NA      NA       6    0.10      NA      NA
20      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
21      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
22      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
23      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
24      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.03      NA      NA
25      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
26      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.08      NA      NA
27      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
28      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
29      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.05      NA      NA
30      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
31      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
32      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
33      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
34      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
35      NA      NA      NA      NA       1    0.00      NA      NA
36      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
   POLLANo POLLAWt ASCSYNo ASCSYWt POLAVNo POLAVWt PLAMANo PLAMAWt
1       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
4       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
5       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
6       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
7       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
8       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
9       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
11      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
12       4     2.6      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
13      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
14      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
15      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
16      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
17      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
18      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
19      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
20      NA      NA       1    0.04      NA      NA      NA      NA
21      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
22      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
23      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
24      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
25      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
26      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
27      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
28      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
29      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
30      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
31      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
32      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
33      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
34      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
35      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
36      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
   UnknowndicotNo UnknowndicotWt UnknownmonocotNo UnknownmonocotWt
1              NA             NA               NA               NA
2              NA             NA               NA               NA
3              NA             NA               NA               NA
4              NA             NA               NA               NA
5              NA             NA               NA               NA
6              NA             NA               NA               NA
7              NA             NA               NA               NA
8              NA             NA               NA               NA
9              NA             NA               NA               NA
10             NA             NA               NA               NA
11             NA             NA               NA               NA
12             NA             NA               NA               NA
13             NA             NA               NA               NA
14             NA             NA               NA               NA
15             NA             NA               NA               NA
16             NA             NA               NA               NA
17             NA             NA               NA               NA
18             NA             NA               NA               NA
19             NA             NA               NA               NA
20             NA             NA               NA               NA
21             NA             NA               NA               NA
22             NA             NA               NA               NA
23              2           2.19                1             0.03
24             NA             NA               NA               NA
25              1             NA               NA               NA
26              1           0.04               NA               NA
27             NA             NA               NA               NA
28             NA             NA               NA               NA
29             NA             NA               NA               NA
30             NA             NA               NA               NA
31             NA             NA               NA               NA
32              1           0.00               NA               NA
33             NA             NA               NA               NA
34             NA             NA               NA               NA
35             NA             NA               NA               NA
36             NA             NA               NA               NA
   TOTALNo TOTALWt samplearea.m.2. g.m.2  kg.ha lb.acre
1       17    0.50          18.532  0.03   0.27    0.24
2       63  296.70          18.532 16.01 160.10  142.97
3       13   23.80          18.532  1.28  12.84   11.47
4       32    0.10          18.532  0.01   0.05    0.05
5       29   41.70          18.532  2.25  22.50   20.09
6       17    0.40          18.532  0.02   0.22    0.19
7        9    0.22          18.532  0.01   0.12    0.11
8       27   46.43          18.532  2.51  25.05   22.37
9       44    6.45          18.532  0.35   3.48    3.11
10      40    2.25          18.532  0.12   1.21    1.08
11      28    8.99          18.532  0.49   4.85    4.33
12      43   40.72          18.532  2.20  21.97   19.62
13      16    4.94          18.532  0.27   2.67    2.38
14      19    0.42          18.532  0.02   0.23    0.20
15      64   16.67          18.532  0.90   9.00    8.03
16      27    0.52          18.532  0.03   0.28    0.25
17      16    0.52          18.532  0.03   0.28    0.25
18      44   39.00          18.532  2.10  21.04   18.79
19      26    0.43          18.532  0.02   0.23    0.21
20      23   85.08          18.532  4.59  45.91   41.00
21      38  119.33          18.532  6.44  64.39   57.50
22       9    4.65          18.532  0.25   2.51    2.24
23     449  241.97          18.532 13.06 130.57  116.60
24     235  101.67          18.532  5.49  54.86   48.99
25      21  100.74          18.532  5.44  54.36   48.54
26       7    1.78          18.532  0.10   0.96    0.86
27      12    4.05          18.532  0.22   2.19    1.95
28     109  328.20          18.532 17.71 177.10  158.15
29      13   30.21          18.532  1.63  16.30   14.56
30      43    3.44          18.532  0.19   1.86    1.66
31      99  410.21          18.532 22.14 221.35  197.67
32      21    1.15          18.532  0.06   0.62    0.55
33      12    0.62          18.532  0.03   0.33    0.30
34      33  158.62          18.532  8.56  85.59   76.43
35       5    1.72          18.532  0.09   0.93    0.83
36      10  112.30          18.532  6.06  60.60   54.11
```

Comment: Try switching geom_boxplot to geom_crossbar

Comment: Is this a case of magical thinking?  `Rot.trt`? And for that matter, ... where are `Crop` and `kg.ha`?

Comment: @jeremycg: Thanks but it doesn't work. R doesn't understand what SE is while I actually found the ymin = xyz+se, ymax=xyz-se formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated piece of code for you. Be sure to load dplyr and tidyr into your R session. The first chunk of code develops a data frame that contains the means and se for the labels. the second chunk develops the plot. Note that I have placed the labels at y=200 in this case, because based on the data that is where they will probably look best.

> datasetlabel <- dataset %>% 
>       group_by(Crop,rotation) %>% 
>       summarise(mean=mean(kg.ha),
>                 se=sd(kg.ha)/n())
>   ggplot(data = dataset, aes(Crop, kg.ha, fill=Crop))+
>       geom_boxplot()+
>       facet_wrap(~rotation)+
>       scale_fill_hue(c=45)+
>       geom_text(aes(x=Crop,y=225,
>                     label=paste(round(mean,1),'+/-',round(se,1),sep=" ")),
>                 data=datasetlabel)

Comment: @all My bad. I copied the wrong piece of the data set. I couldn't paste the complete table for character limit. The piece shown in the question is half of the whole data table